# How can I determine the coordinates of a point on the arc a circle if it has moved 2 units counter clockwise

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An ant starts on ($0,3$) on a circle with $3$ radius and walks $2$ units counterclockwise along the arc of a circle. Find the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of where the ant ends up.

I only know how to move in a straight line (up-down, left-right) to determine coordinates.

How would I begin to attempt this problem? I imagine I have to plug in a $2$ into some sort of formula.

Comment: Is the circle centered at the origin?

Answer (score 2):

Two units counter-clockwise means that you're arclength traveled is 2.  The formula for arclength is $S = \theta r$.  So, you have $2 = \theta *3$.  This gives you the subtended angle.  Now, use trig to find $x$ and $y$ coordinates.
$$\frac{x}{r} = \cos(\theta)$$
$$\frac{y}{r} = \sin(\theta)$$

Comment: Bear in mind that this won't work for any initial starting point on the circle. In the general case, you need something like:

x' = x*cos θ + y*sin θ .... y' = -x*sin θ + y*cosθ

Answer (score 0):

You probably know the equation for the circumference of a circle, that is $2 \pi r$. So for this circle, you know he circumference is $6 \pi$ units long. Now your ant only walked 2 units. So by ratio he walked $\frac{1}{3 \pi}$ of the circle.

Now you can plug these values into the we'll know formulae for angles and x,y coordinates and you'll find your answer. It won't be a nice exact point though.

Comment: I am wondering what does well known formulae are. Would you mind showing?

Comment: Sure, $x=r \cos(\theta)$ and $y=r \sin(\theta)$. You know $r=3$ and I just gave you the $\theta$.

Comment: Where are you taking into account the starting position on the circle (0,3)? Applying this equations gives you the same result regardless.